# Access parameters of function inside class

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I want a class, which can be initialised with a function. I also want to be able to set the parameters of this function. The code below does not work, but is there a way to achieve something like this?

```
class model {
    private:
        double parameter;
        double (*f)(parameter);

    public:
        model(double (*)(double));
        void setParams(double);
};
```

in the source file:

```
model::model(double (*func)(double param)){
    f = func;
    parameter = param;
}

void model::setParams(double param){
     parameter = param;
}
```

So, how can I access the parameter of the function I want the class to be initialised with?

Comment: Take a look at the std::bind function template. I think it already does what you want: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/

Comment: I guess you need std::bind

Comment: Thank you! Can you show me how this would look like? I am not quite sure how to adjust the usage of bind for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `std::bind` doesn't fit your requirements, it looks like you want this:

```
class model {
    private:
        double parameter;
        double (*f)(double);

    public:
        model(double (*)(double));
        void setParams(double);
        double call();
};

model::model(double (*func)(double)) 
    : parameter(0.0), f(func) {

}

void model::setParams(double param){
     parameter = param;
}


double model::call()
{
    return f(parameter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Currently, I don't see where you tell the code that the variable parameter is actually the parameter of the function f. Can you help here?

Comment: @beginneR I'm not quite sure what you mean. You pass `parameter` to the function when you call it, which is what makes it the function's parameter. (See edit.)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. This cleared things up for me.

Comment: How would you do this using std::bind (and std::function)?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor currently just takes a pointer to a function with the given signature. It doesn't  matter that you gave the parameter the name 'param'. All that counts is the signature.
So why not just extend your construtor to pass the parameters for the function to call too:

```
typedef double (*ThatFunction) (double);
class model
{
private:
    double _param;
    ThatFunction _thatFunction;

public:
    model(ThatFunction thatFunction, double param);
...
}

model::model(ThatFunction thatFunction, double p)
{
    _thatFunction = thatFunction;
    _param = p;
}
```